# $xRx'$ and $yRy'$ implies $f(x,y)Rf(x',y')$

Tags: terminology, relations

Let $R$ be a binary relation. Is there a name for the following property?

- $f(x,y)Rf(x',y')\quad$ if $xRx'$ and $yRy'$

Note:$f$ is a function.

Comment: This would seem to be a property of $f$, whatever that is, as well as of $R$.

Comment: This is related to _congruence relations_ ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation), [ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Congruence_Relation)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: The composition law $f$ is *compatible* with the binary relation $R$.